# How to correctly expand a file name with spaces as a variable within double quotes in Bash?

Tags: bash, sh, double-quotes, variable-expansion

Minimal example:

```bash
f="/tmp/a file"
cmd="cat \"$f\""

set -x

$cmd
```

How do I correctly handle `$f` here such that cmd becomes `cat "/tmp/a file"` (double or single quote).

`cmd="cat '$f'"` also doesn't work.

Comment: This might help: [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/3776858)

Comment: Don't store commands in variables, just execute them directly (or use a function or possibly an array instead). Variables are for storing data, functions are for storing executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)